# Pushing news to my iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios

What would be the easiest way to set up a way in which my iPhone app can read news data online from my website, for example. I want to be able to push news or updates to the bottom of the app such as "Check out our new app, blah blah" or something along those lines. I thought of one way, but I didn't know if there's better ways.

1. Keep some html file on my server (my website), and have the iPhone read that html data

Any other ideas? Anyone have experience in this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a blog or are familiar with some popular blogging software, you can likely take advantage of RSS feeds that are automatically generated for you.

For example, you can have Wordpress automatically generate RSS for a post type, a tag, a category, or pretty much anything else that returns a set of posts. Your application could then consume that data without you needing to manually update anything code-laden, just add to the blog and it's available in the feed.

Comment: Do those news apps like Bloomberg, ABCNews, CBSnews, apps use the same technique?